# Is it possible to deploy a iOS app using Google Cloud Build?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ios, build-server

I have been using CircleCI to build the iOS app with the latest macOS Container `Xcode 11.3.1 (Build 11C505)`. Currently looking to use the GCP ecosystem for future builds, but can't find a way to use macOS as the build server.

Looks like I am stuck using CircleCI, unless @googlecloud is looking into this?

Answer (score 2):

After some investigation, I reached the conclusion that probably you can not do it because Cloud Build requires Docker, which is based on Linux VM whereas XCode is based on iOS.

Additionally, I created a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/149469695) on your behalf, in order to include this functionality to Cloud Build of GCP. You may star it so that it gets more visibility and also for you to receive any relevant updates regarding this.